# Invoking a segue associated with the Detail View from the Main View

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I have a split view controller and the main view has a "Note" button on a navigation bar which should push a view(Note Gallery ViewController) that contains a list of saved notes onto Detail View. In the following screenshot, "Categories" is the Master View and "List of Events" is the Detail View. As you can see, there is a segue between the "List of Events" and "Note Gallery".

[image]

What I would like to do is pushing the "Note Gallery" as a Detail view when "Note" button on the Main View is tapped. So far, I have tried using delegate/protocal approach where protocol is defined inside the Master View and it is implemented inside the Detail View. If I call self.performSegue to push "Note Gallery" view, "Note Gallery" view does not show navigation bar (Even if I force it to show with setNavigationBarHidden with false value). If I call performSegue from the navigation controller (self.navigationController?.performSegue), I get identifier not found exception. I don't want to move Note button to the Detail view since I want to make Note button accessible from the Main View. How can I resolve this issu, and here's an excerpt of my code :

```
/* Master View */

// Define delegate for updating children views
protocol ChildViewDelegate: class {
   func pushInNoteView()
}

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate  {
   weak var delegate: ChildViewDelegate?

   // Handles tapping on Note button
   @IBAction func noteTapped(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Push Note View onto any active detailed view
      self.delegate?.pushInNoteView()

   }
}

/* Detail View */
extension CategoryDetailTableViewController: ChildViewDelegate {
   func pushInNoteView() {
      // This approach does not show navigation bar
      self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNoteView", sender: self)

      // This approach gives identifier not found exception
      self.navigationController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showNoteView", sender: self)
   }

}
```

Comment: Do you actually have the identifier set on the segue?

Comment: Yup, I do have identifier set. That's why it works when I call self.performSegue. The problem with that is, navigationbar isn't shown. With self.navigationController?.performSegue, I get "reason: 'Receiver (<UINavigationController: 0x7fa429044800>) has no segue with identifier 'showNoteView''".

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is that you did not give identifier to your segue in main.storyboard.

[Here is how to do it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnLIH.png)
In your main.storyboard select your segue as shown in image and assign it an identifier in identity inspector as shown in top right side of the image.

Now create navigation controller and make "root view controller" relationship with your Master View. Then use `performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: nil)` to move to next view controller.

Hope that I've solved your problem!

Comment: I found the culprit. It's because the segue isn't connected directly to the nav controller. It's connected to the view which in turn connected to the nav controller. So for nav controller, the identifier is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the mistakes I have made :

The reason why I'm getting identifier not defined error is because the segue is not connected between the navigation controller and the "Note Gallery" view. It's connected between the "Note Gallery" view and the "Category Detail" view which in turn connected to the navigation controller. Therefore, the identifier is not defined for the navigation controller.

The reason why navigation bar is hidden is because I'm not pushing "Note Gallery" view onto the navigation controller. Instead, I was just calling prepare segue.

Solution :

It's fairly simple. I just push the "Note Gallery" view on the Navigation Controller just like this :

```
if let noteVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NoteGalleryView") {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(noteVC, animated: true)
        }
```